# MySql Select latest rows, then group, then count

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following columns; id, post_id, status, and datetime. Every time a post(post_id) is updated, a row is inserted with the latest status and datetime timestamp. I am created a pie chart of by status. Therefore I must first SELECT the latest entry of a post (ignoring all past updates), then COUNT how many rows are returned and group by status. What does my query look like?

Comment: You tell us. What does your query currently look like? Show that you have put in some effort.

Comment: My current query looks like this: SELECT status, COUNT(*) AS statusCnt FROM inspections GROUP BY status. It returns a count of everything and does not filter out past entires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*) AS statusCnt
FROM inspections
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM inspections GROUP BY post_id)
GROUP BY status
```

Untested alternative:

```
SELECT i1.status, COUNT(i1.*) AS statusCnt
FROM inspections i1
    JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(i2.id) AS maxID FROM inspections i2 GROUP BY i2.post_id
    ) AS innerTbl ON i1.id = innerTbl.id
GROUP BY i1.status
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Struggling for hours. Thanks for the help!

Comment: While this does work, it takes too long to load the results. Since I am not an sql expert by any means, is there anyway to make this more efficient? There is about 7000 rows in the inspections table.

Comment: @vanreus Just added an alternative version that may (or may not) help.

Comment: @TusharMonirul  "Wrong" according to whom? Using what data? With what expected results?  OP accepted the answer and said "This was exactly what I needed", so I don't think it is the wrong answer for this question.  If you have your own question, feel free to post it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT *,MAX(time) FROM table GROUP BY post_id) As b
```

As per my interpretation of your question, query should be like this

Comment: `SELECT *,MAX(time)` That's not going to do what I think you think it is going to do. The values contained within `*` are not necessarily those that correspond to the row with the most recent time.

Comment: I think your result is the same as `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT post_id) FROM table` which is a single scalar value.